# java android, onActivityResult not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I need to implement my app to other Android project and now I am facing a problem that method onActivityResult doesn't work. What I want to achieve is that Intent i will return the result to class 1 (G_map) but I can't figure it out how to get it works.

I have class 1:

```
public class G_map extends GraphObj{

    private Context contextOwn;
    private Activity act;

    public G_map(GraphObjMgr gom, final Context context, GraphSetting gs) {
        super(gom, context, gs, R.layout.test_map);
        Intent i = new Intent(contextOwn, PickLocationActivity.class);
        act.startActivityForResult(i, 1);

    //@Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("State", "This won't start.");
   }
}
```

The activity PickLocationActivity starts properly and from second class I need to obtain result to the first class. The method onActivityResult can't be @Override and if I comment it then the method is never used. What can I do about it? In my app, it works properly and I don't need to use act.startActivityForResult but startActivityForResult.

I guess I need to somehow connect "act" with onActivityResult method but I don't know how. Any suggestion would be helpful!

The class 2:

```
public class PickLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
     ...
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Location Address", predictions.getPlaces().get(position).getPlaceDesc());
            intent.putExtra("placeID", predictions.getPlaces().get(position).getPlaceID());
            setResult(CUSTOM_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE, intent);
            finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The method onActivityResult can't be @Override and if I comment it then the method is never used. What can I do about it?

Override `onActivityResult()` in the activity or fragment from which you called `startActivityForResult()`.

BTW, the code in your first snippet will crash with a `NullPointerException`, as you do not assign a value to `act`, let alone before you call `startActivityForResult()` on it.

Comment: I actually assign a value to act like: act = (Activity) context. I don't get it how you mean the I need to Override onActivityResult() in the activity from which I call startActivityResult because I am doing that in G_map class and it is not working...

Comment: @RobinPopelka: `G_map` is not an `Activity`, and it is definitely not the activity on which you are calling `startActivityForResult()`. Whatever Java class is the implementation behind your `act` field needs to be the one implementing `onActivityResult()`.